# Plotly-Dash: 3 callbacks, same Input list - 2 being called, 1 not

Tags: python, plotly-dash

3 callbacks with same Input list, 2 being called but not 1. In the debugger for the 3rd notice execution jumps from the Input list straight out of the function. Any suggests welcome ...

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('firstcallback', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('firstdropdown', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('seconddropdown', 'value')])
def firstgoodcallback(first, second):
    print("firstgoodcallback") #prints ok
    return u'{} is a reference to {}'.format(first, second)

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('secondcallback', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('firstdropdown', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('seconddropdown', 'value')])
def secondgoodcallback(first, second):
    print("secondgoodcallback") #prints ok
    return u'{} is a second reference to {}'.format(first, second)

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('thirdcallback', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('firstdropdown', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('seconddropdown', 'value')])
def set_display_children(first, second):
    print("helloWorld") #doesn't get this far    
    return u'{} is a third reference to {}'.format(first, second)
```

And both `'firstdropdown'`, `'seconddropdown'` are initialized with default values at launch and all callbacks are in the same module which also has the `name==main` guard. Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm there's someone subscribing to `thirdcallback`? Also, I guess name of the second function should be `secondgoodcallback`.

Comment: Changed the second function name and also discovered the issue in the meantime. In my actual code I had the Output for the non-working function wrapped in list [ ] but seems like for single Output that does not work, only for multiple outputs.